# Two TD's next to eachother, one is taking up 100% width?

Tags: html, css, html-table, html-email

I've got two td's next to eachother (in a html5 email) and one is being pushed outside the table? I'm not sure why! I'm looking to have two columns next to eachother for text.

Thanks!

```
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#fdfcf8" style="padding:10px; padding-top:0; border-top: 0px solid #fdfcf8; font-family:arial, sans-serif; border-left:1px solid #fdfcf8; border-right:1px solid #fdfcf8; border-bottom:1px solid #fdfcf8;color: #003F6B;">hehe
                </td>
                <td bgcolor="#fdfcf8" style="padding:10px; padding-top:0; border-top: 0px solid #fdfcf8; font-family:arial, sans-serif; border-left:1px solid #fdfcf8; border-right:1px solid #fdfcf8; border-bottom:1px solid #fdfcf8;color: #003F6B;">hehe
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to tell from your example code - look in other rows above/below for wide content which is pushing the width of that column.

Content widths in one row will affect the width of cells in other rows that are part of the same table.

Comment: I went through and re-read all the code. It turns out to be that the entire email was enclosed in a single column, so trying to add nested columns inside ended with this issue. I solved the issue by testing a new table inside. Thanks for the speedy response! :)